# Python - parsing a string with letters and numbers not blocked together

Tags: python, parsing

I'm having trouble parsing out a string that contains letters and numbers and getting a list back. For example:

```
>>> s = '105Bii2016'
>>> foo(s)
['105', 'Bii', '2016']
```

Right now I can only do it if the numbers are together:

```
def foo(s):
    num, letter = '', ''
    for i in s:
        if i.isdigit():
            num += i
        else:
            letter += i
    return [letter, num]
```

And when I call this:

```
>>> s = '1234gdfh1234'

>>> foo(s)

['gdfh', '12341234']
```

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: `print re.split("[a-zA-Z]",s)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- I think you need some capturing parenthesis in there.  Maybe easier is `re.split(r'(\d+)',s)`.  Of course, both of these assume that either the string starts with a character or a number and if you guess wrong, you get empty strings at the beginning (or end) of the list which means you probably would need to filter it...

Comment: yeah you are correct ... i was distracted and not thinking clearly :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> s = '1234gdfh1234'
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> print [''.join(v) for k,v in groupby(s,str.isdigit)]
['1234', 'gdfh', '1234']
```

---

Another solution uses regex:

```
>>> print [x for x in re.split(r'(\d+)',s) if x]
['1234', 'gdfh', '1234']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from re import split
>>> s = '1234gdfh1234'
>>> [i for i in split(r'(\d+)',s) if i]
['1234', 'gdfh', '1234']
```